Unable to Resolve '../Platform/utilites' using React-Native for IOS with Metro Bundler
I use react-native with NX, pnpm and Metro to build a custom cross-platform application for a rather complex project that i have.
I do not need the web-rendering part just yet.
When i'm trying to generate the main.jsbundle in order to add it in xcode before building i cannot seem to solve this error:
[Nx] Unable to resolve with default PNPM resolver: ../Utilities/Platform
[Nx] Unable to resolve with any resolver: ../Utilities/Platform
error Cannot resolve ./Libraries/Image/Image.
Error: Cannot resolve ./Libraries/Image/Image
    at /Users/XXX/Desktop/econofac/node_modules/.pnpm/@nx+react-native@19.1.1_@swc-node+register@1.9.1_@swc+core@1.5.7_@types+node@20.12.7_eslint@8_can2ihzkfgasdczhk3lorolynm/node_modules/@nx/react-native/plugins/metro-resolver.js:33:15
    at Object.resolve (/Users/XXX/Desktop/econofac/node_modules/.pnpm/metro-resolver@0.80.9/node_modules/metro-resolver/src/resolve.js:32:12)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/XXX/Desktop/econofac/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:73:31)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/XXX/Desktop/econofac/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:232:43)
    at /Users/XXX/Desktop/econofac/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:156:21
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/XXX/Desktop/econofac/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:42:25)
    at visit (/Users/XXX/Desktop/econofac/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:83:30)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async visit (/Users/XXX/Desktop/econofac/node_modules/.pnpm/metro@0.80.9/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:92:5)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

The way that i'm trying to generate the bundle from is: pnpm nx run cliford:bundle-ios
which refer to (apps/cliford/project.json):
"bundle-ios": {
      "executor": "@nx/react-native:bundle",
      "outputs": ["{options.bundleOutput}"],
      "options": {
        "entryFile": "src/main.tsx",
        "platform": "ios",
        "bundleOutput": "dist/apps/mobile/ios/main.jsbundle"
      }
    },

(running with --verbose does not add any log)
Here is my package.json since it's probably usefull information:
{
  "name": "econofac",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "test-parser": "jest",
    "postinstall": "./patch.sh;"
  },
  "private": true,
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "3.9.11",
    "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support": "0.10.0",
    "@apollo/server": "4.10.4",
    "@cobo/apm-rum-react-native": "0.6.0",
    "@elastic/apm-rum": "5.16.0",
    "@elastic/apm-rum-react": "2.0.2",
    "@elastic/elasticsearch": "8.13.1",
    "@emotion/cache": "11.11.0",
    "@emotion/react": "11.11.4",
    "@emotion/server": "11.11.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.11.5",
    "@formatjs/intl": "2.10.1",
    "@formatjs/intl-numberformat": "8.10.1",
    "@google-cloud/local-auth": "3.0.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "3.3.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.15.15",
    "@mui/material": "5.15.15",
    "@mui/material-nextjs": "5.15.11",
    "@mui/system": "5.15.15",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "7.5.1",
    "@nestjs/apollo": "12.1.0",
    "@nestjs/axios": "3.0.2",
    "@nestjs/common": "10.3.8",
    "@nestjs/config": "3.2.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "10.3.8",
    "@nestjs/elasticsearch": "10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "12.1.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "10.3.8",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "4.0.2",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "14.2.2",
    "@paralleldrive/cuid2": "2.2.2",
    "@prisma/client": "5.12.1",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "1.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "13.6.9",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.7.0",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "1.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "19.2.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "19.2.2",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.3.1",
    "@react-native/gradle-plugin": "0.75.0-main",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.26",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "2.2.3",
    "@rneui/base": "4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@rneui/themed": "4.0.0-rc.8",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.37.2",
    "@tanstack/query-core": "5.29.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "5.29.2",
    "@teovilla/react-native-web-maps": "0.9.5",
    "apollo3-cache-persist": "0.15.0",
    "archiver": "7.0.1",
    "array-buffer-byte-length": "1.0.1",
    "async": "3.2.5",
    "aws-sdk": "2.1602.0",
    "axios": "1.6.8",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "5.0.2",
    "bcrypt": "5.1.1",
    "call-bind": "1.0.7",
    "chart.js": "4.4.2",
    "class-transformer": "0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "0.14.1",
    "clsx": "2.1.0",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "date-fns": "3.6.0",
    "deep-equal": "2.2.3",
    "deepmerge": "4.3.1",
    "define-data-property": "1.1.4",
    "docparser-node": "1.2.2",
    "elastic-apm-node": "4.5.2",
    "es-errors": "1.3.0",
    "es-get-iterator": "1.1.3",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "12.7.2",
    "express": "4.19.2",
    "firebase-admin": "12.1.0",
    "follow-redirects": "1.15.6",
    "function-bind": "1.1.2",
    "get-intrinsic": "1.2.4",
    "googleapis": "134.0.0",
    "gopd": "1.0.1",
    "gql-query-builder": "3.8.0",
    "graphql": "16.8.1",
    "graphql-anywhere": "4.2.8",
    "graphql-subscriptions": "2.0.0",
    "graphql-tag": "2.12.6",
    "graphql-ws": "5.16.0",
    "has-property-descriptors": "1.0.2",
    "has-proto": "1.0.3",
    "has-symbols": "1.0.3",
    "hasown": "2.0.2",
    "iron-session": "8.0.1",
    "is-arguments": "1.1.1",
    "is-array-buffer": "3.0.4",
    "is-date-object": "1.0.5",
    "is-map": "2.0.3",
    "is-regex": "1.1.4",
    "is-set": "2.0.3",
    "is-shared-array-buffer": "1.0.3",
    "is-weakmap": "2.0.2",
    "is-weakset": "2.0.3",
    "isarray": "2.0.5",
    "jsc-android": "250231.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "9.0.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "loglevel": "1.9.1",
    "md5": "2.3.0",
    "metro": "0.80.9",
    "moti": "0.28.1",
    "nanoid": "5.0.7",
    "native-base": "3.4.28",
    "nestjs-elastic-apm": "1.3.0",
    "next": "14.2.2",
    "node-cron": "3.0.3",
    "node-fetch": "3.3.2",
    "nodemailer": "6.9.13",
    "object-inspect": "1.13.1",
    "object-is": "1.1.6",
    "object-keys": "1.1.1",
    "object.assign": "4.1.5",
    "pdf-parse": "1.1.1",
    "permalink": "0.1.1",
    "prisma-nestjs-graphql": "20.0.2",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "2.2.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "13.1.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-hook-form": "7.51.3",
    "react-i18next": "14.1.0",
    "react-intl": "6.6.5",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-blob-util": "0.19.9",
    "react-native-cli": "2.0.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.16.0",
    "react-native-localize": "3.1.0",
    "react-native-maps": "1.15.6",
    "react-native-navigation": "7.39.2",
    "react-native-pdf": "6.7.4",
    "react-native-permissions": "4.1.5",
    "react-native-push-notification": "8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.8.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "3.30.1",
    "react-native-section-list-get-item-layout": "2.2.3",
    "react-native-svg": "15.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "10.0.3",
    "react-number-format": "5.3.4",
    "react-redux": "9.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-waypoint": "10.3.0",
    "redux": "5.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "3.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.2.2",
    "regexp.prototype.flags": "1.5.2",
    "rxjs": "7.8.1",
    "set-function-length": "1.2.2",
    "shelljs": "0.8.5",
    "side-channel": "1.0.6",
    "stream-buffers": "3.0.2",
    "stripe": "15.3.0",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "0.11.0",
    "tslib": "2.6.2",
    "which-boxed-primitive": "1.0.2",
    "which-collection": "1.0.2",
    "which-typed-array": "1.1.15",
    "yup": "1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.24.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "7.24.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.24.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.24.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.24.6",
    "@directus/extensions-sdk": "11.0.3",
    "@emotion/babel-plugin": "11.11.0",
    "@eslint/eslintrc": "2.1.1",
    "@eslint/js": "8.57.0",
    "@formatjs/ts-transformer": "3.13.12",
    "@nestjs/cli": "10.3.2",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "10.1.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "10.3.8",
    "@nx-tools/nx-container": "5.3.0",
    "@nx/cypress": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/detox": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/devkit": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/eslint": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/jest": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/js": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/nest": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/next": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/node": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/playwright": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/plugin": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/react": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/react-native": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/storybook": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/vite": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/web": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/webpack": "19.1.1",
    "@nx/workspace": "19.1.1",
    "@playwright/test": "1.36.0",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "0.5.11",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "13.6.5",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "12.3.6",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.1",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.73.5",
    "@svgr/webpack": "8.1.0",
    "@swc-node/register": "1.9.1",
    "@swc/cli": "0.3.12",
    "@swc/core": "1.5.7",
    "@swc/helpers": "0.5.11",
    "@swc/plugin-emotion": "2.5.124",
    "@tanstack/eslint-plugin-query": "5.28.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "5.4.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "15.0.6",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "12.4.5",
    "@types/archiver": "6.0.2",
    "@types/cookie": "0.6.0",
    "@types/deep-equal": "1.0.4",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.12",
    "@types/md5": "2.3.5",
    "@types/node": "20.12.7",
    "@types/nodemailer": "6.4.14",
    "@types/react": "18.3.1",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "13.1.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.3.0",
    "@types/react-native-push-notification": "8.1.4",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "6.4.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "7.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "7.7.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "4.2.1",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "1.5.0",
    "@vitest/ui": "1.5.0",
    "babel-jest": "29.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "2.3.3",
    "babel-plugin-formatjs": "10.5.14",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "6.9.4",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.1",
    "cypress": "13.9.0",
    "detox": "20.20.2",
    "dotenv": "16.4.5",
    "esbuild": "0.20.2",
    "eslint": "8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.3",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "2.15.2",
    "eslint-plugin-formatjs": "4.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-playwright": "0.15.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "execa": "8.0.1",
    "expo": "50.0.17",
    "husky": "9.0.11",
    "jest": "29.7.0",
    "jest-circus": "29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-node": "29.7.0",
    "jest-react-native": "18.0.0",
    "jsdom": "24.0.0",
    "metro-babel-register": "0.80.9",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.77.0",
    "metro-resolver": "0.80.9",
    "nx": "19.1.1",
    "prettier": "3.2.5",
    "pretty-quick": "4.0.0",
    "prisma": "5.12.1",
    "react-devtools": "5.1.0",
    "react-devtools-core": "5.1.0",
    "react-native-asset": "2.1.1",
    "react-native-config": "1.5.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "3.4.11",
    "react-native-gradle-plugin": "0.71.19",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "1.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.19.11",
    "react-refresh": "0.14.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "swc-loader": "0.2.6",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.2",
    "ts-node": "10.9.2",
    "typescript": "5.4.5",
    "url-loader": "4.1.1",
    "verdaccio": "5.30.3",
    "vite": "5.2.9",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "~3.8.3",
    "vitest": "1.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "5.1.4"
  },
  "nx": {
    "includedScripts": []
  },
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "metro-file-map": "0.76.0"
    }
  }
}

I've already tried the solution from this similar stackoverflow issue and from the react-native-maps github as well. But in their issue they seem to have problem when creating bundle for web which does not fit my target. (or is it maybe actually related ? i'm not sure).
I'm not sure as well if this error might be related or causing this issue but this shows up multiple times as well when i'm trying to bundle transform[stderr]: Missing transform.routerRoot option in Metro bundling request, falling back to 'app' as routes directory.
